# How do i use views with a custom entity?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I defined a custom entity with a few bundles.  Is it possible to display these using Views?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you used [entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module, then this is done pretty much out of the box, see my blogpost on [Integrating entities with Views](http://drupalsun.com/googletorp/2011/07/12/integrating-entities-views) for more details.

If you didn't use entity API module or don't want to, you can make the views integration yourself using `hook_views_data`.