# How to add relationship in view for custom entity

Tags: entities, views

I have an entity that references `node` and `user` via `nid` and `uid` fields.

I have created an entity around my schema and would like to use it in views. I can create a view based on a new entity that shows fields from the entity.

Now I want to add relationships to `node` and `user` so I could pull fields from them. So I want to show fields from related user and node, [not my entity bundles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/how-do-i-use-views-with-a-custom-entity).

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I cannot post answer to that question, as it was marked as dupe by mistake. I will post solution here - http://drupal.org/node/1208874. It states that `hook_view_data` is not the right place to define entity fields for views, `EntityDefaultViewsController` should be used instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

two solutions:

1)using relation ,relation end field,relation UI

2)using `hook_views_data_alter` example from commerce module:

```
function hook_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  // Expose the uid as a relationship to users.
  $data['users']['uc_orders'] = array(
    'title' => t('Orders'),
    'help' => t('Relate a user to the orders they have placed. This relationship will create one record for each order placed by the user.'),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'uc_orders',
      'base field' => 'uid',
      'relationship field' => 'uid',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('orders'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: First option is not an option really as I already have a `uid` field in my schema. Second option sounds better, but I read somewhere that you are not supposed to use `data` hooks with entity api.

Comment: Could not find anything better than the second option and it worked. Tnx!

Comment: One note on this. If you already have a custom views implementation, this will not work as an hook_alter, you need to add this to your view implementation code.

Answer (score 10):

Entity API supports this out of the box, but you will have to let it know which entity your data represents. If Entity API encounters a field containing numeric data it will by default assign it the type 'integer'. Just change the type to the right entity type and you can define the relations in Views:

```
<?php
  /**
   * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
   */
  function my_entity_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
    $info['my_entity']['properties']['nid']['type'] = 'node';
    $info['my_entity']['properties']['uid']['type'] = 'user';
    $info['my_entity']['properties']['tid']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term';
  }
?>
```