# List custom entity in Views

Tags: views, entities

I would like to simply output all created entities from my custom entity type through a View. Does anyone have an article or module or code to point me in the right direction, my searches didn't bring much up (only entity relationships to certain fields, but I want all the entities)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/how-do-i-use-views-with-a-custom-entity

Comment: I have added what I was missing in my hook_entity_info but the article gives no indication of how to actually use the entity in a view. Even in a view with no filters the view will only print all nodes on the site, not entities. So leaving this question open.