# Is it possible to approve an Enitity Form?

Tags: entities

Is it possible to approve a submitted Entity Form by a specific user/role ?

For example, I have a Leave Request Entity form to be submitted by the employee(role). The manager(role) will approve or disapprove the leave request.

Thanks for those who can give me some ideas.
(Im a beginner and learning drupal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Define a field called "Approval Status" in your entity form with two values Approved / Unapproved
- Be Default set it to "Unapproved"
- Use Views to list your custom entities see below post for reference

[How do i use views with a custom entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/how-do-i-use-views-with-a-custom-entity)

- Update "Approval Status" using VBO. See this [article](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3633/drupal-7-how-to-add-your-own-custom-operation-in-views-bulk-operation-vbo) to find out how to create simple action.

Comment: I would try that. Thank you so much for the great idea.